# Using CKEditor 5 DecoupledEditor from plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to build a custom editor using the CKEditor 5 Framework with my own plugins.

My `webpack.config.js` contains the lines:

```
module.exports = {
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
    entry: './app.js',
...
```

So when I run

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

It generate a `bundle.js` file for me, which include the content of my `app.js`.

If my `app.js` file calls `DecoupledEditor.create(...)` and if I build it all with `./node_modules/.bin/webpack` and then include `<script src='dist/bundle.js' />` in my HTML file, anything is working, and I get a CKEditor with my own plugin :)

But what I really need is the ability to call `DecoupledEditor.create(...)` from my own custom hand written JavaScript* which is not build using webpack and I cant get that to work.

How do I use CKEditor 5 DecoupledEditor from a plain javascript?

I guess i need to import the class but if I do a

```
import DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-decoupled/src/decouplededitor';
```

in my own javascript, I just get the error

> "TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: @ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-decoupled/src/decouplededitor"

*Really calling from GWT, but that don't really matter here.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if I use

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/10.0.1/decoupled-document/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

instead of my own bundle.js I can call DecoupledEditor.create(...) directly from my javascript without any import. So I guess my issue is that I fail to build DecoupledEditor with my build script.